# how to find an id in an array of objects in karate API testing

Tags: automation, karate

My json is of this sort:

```
{ "attributes":[
{"key_id": 123,
"value": v1},
{"key_id": 456,
"value": v2},
{"key_id": 789,
"value": v3}
]
}
```

Now for this array of objects response in karate framework I need to know how can I find a specific keyid and then find the value corresponding to it and then match it to my required answer?